# Fancybox thumbnail image not display in popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2, flexslider

I used flexslider wtih fancybox. When I click on main image in flexslider then thumbnail not display in popup.

In Fancybox version 3.2.5 thumbnail is display proper. But, in fancybox version 2.1.5 thumbnail slider display. But, image is not display.

How can I set it in version 2.1.5?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Example : https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/QQdXwx

```
<div class="container">
      <div id="slider" class="flexslider" style="width:450px;height:400px;">
         <ul class="slides">
            <li>
               <a href="img/1.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/1.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/2.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/2.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/3.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/3.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/4.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/4.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua5.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua5.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua6.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua6.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua1.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua1.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua2.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua2.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua3.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua3.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua4.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua4.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua5.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua5.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="img/noctua6.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
               <img src="img/noctua6.jpg" />
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
         <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua1.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua1.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua2.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua2.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua3.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua3.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua4.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua4.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua5.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua5.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua6.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua6.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua1.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua1.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua2.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua2.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua3.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua3.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua4.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua4.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua5.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua5.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="img/noctua6.jpg">
               <img src="img/noctua6.jpg" />
             </a>
            </li>
            <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
         </ul>
      </div>
      </div><div class="container">
  <div id="slider" class="flexslider" style="width:450px;height:400px;">
     <ul class="slides">
        <li>
           <a href="img/1.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/1.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/2.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/2.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/3.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/3.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/4.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/4.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/5.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/5.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/6.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/6.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/1.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/1.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/2.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/2.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/3.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/3.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/4.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/4.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/5.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/5.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="img/6.jpg" rel="gallery" data-fancybox="images">
           <img src="img/6.jpg" />
           </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <a href="img/1.jpg">
           <img src="img/1.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/2.jpg">
           <img src="img/2.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/3.jpg">
           <img src="img/3.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/4.jpg">
           <img src="img/4.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/5.jpg">
           <img src="img/5.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/6.jpg">
           <img src="img/6.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/1.jpg">
           <img src="img/1.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/2.jpg">
           <img src="img/2.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/3.jpg">
           <img src="img/3.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/4.jpg">
           <img src="img/4.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/5.jpg">
           <img src="img/5.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/6.jpg">
           <img src="img/6.jpg" />
         </a>
        </li>
        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
     </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

=> jQuery :

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 70,
    itemMargin: 10,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
});
$().fancybox({
  selector : '.slides :not(.clone) a',
  helpers : {
     overlay : {
        locked : false,
        arrows : true,
        nextClick : true
     }
  },
  hash   : false,
  thumbs : {
    autoStart : true,
    axis      : 'x'
  }
});
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  helpers : {
      thumbs : {
          width : 50,
          height : 50
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: make a working example in [**fiddle**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/) or something else

Comment: You can add fancybox 2.1.5 in this link. Current 3.2 version in this example